# Why is std::mutex a standard-layout class?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, stdmutex

[[thread.mutex.class]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.mutex#class-3):

> [...] It is a standard-layout class ([class.prop]).

What is the reason for this requirement?

Comment: Wild guess : it may be for compatibility with preexisting threading libraries like pthread? Just about every threading library before `std::mutex` had a C API.

Comment: Another guess: every compiler's implementation of std mutex was a standard layout class, so why not require it?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, but what benefits? (Except maybe making some standard library implementations jump thru the hoops to keep this property (I'm not kidding))

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, actually you may be right, the intention might be to allow building pthreads interface on top of C++ mutexes...

Comment: ABI compatibility maybe? C11 has a `mtx_t` (well, threading support in C11 is optional, but assuming it *is* there). And presumably if `std::mutex` is standard layout, and it has a `mtx_t` member, then they are pointer-interconvertible. Such things have precedent. `std::complex` and the C11 `_Complex` specifier (explicitly binary compatible). Then there's `std::atmoic` and the C11 `_Atomic` specifier.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Interoperability with the associated C interface. From [N2320](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2320.html) (*Multi-threading Library for Standard C++*):

> The C level interface has been removed from this proposal with the
> following rationale:
>
> - As long as we specify that the key types in this proposal **are standard-layout types** (which we have done), WG14 is still free to
>   standardize a C interface which interoperates with this C++ interface.
> - WG14 is in a better position to solve the cancellation interoperability problem than WG21 is. [...]
> - WG14 asked WG21 to take the lead on this issue. We feel we can best take lead by specifying only a C++ interface which has the minimum
>   hooks in it to support a future C interoperating interface (**i.e.
>   types are standard-layout types**). We feel we should stop short of
>   actually specifying that C interface in the C++ standard. WG14 can do
>   a better job with the C interface and a future C++ standard can then
>   import it by reference.