# Why is std::mutex so much worse than std::shared_mutex in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stdmutex

Ran the following in Visual Studio 2022 in release mode:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <shared_mutex>
#include <iostream>

std::mutex mx;
std::shared_mutex smx;

constexpr int N = 100'000'000;

int main()
{
    auto t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i != N; i++)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l{ mx };
    }
    auto t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i != N; i++)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::shared_mutex> l{ smx };
    }
    auto t3 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    auto d1 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(t2 - t1);
    auto d2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double>>(t3 - t2);

    std::cout << "mutex " << d1.count() << "s;  shared_mutex " << d2.count() << "s\n";
    std::cout << "mutex " << sizeof(mx) << " bytes;  shared_mutex " << sizeof(smx) << " bytes \n";
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
mutex 2.01147s;  shared_mutex 1.32065s
mutex 80 bytes;  shared_mutex 8 bytes
```

Why so?

It is unexpected that more rich in features `std::shared_mutex` is faster than `std::mutex`, which is strictly a subset in its features.

Comment: I wrote my own similar to yours measurement code on my Windows 1.2 Ghz laptop and simple spin-lock works strictly `24 ns` in a loop, std::mutex `75-85 ns`, std::shared_mutex `42-45 ns`.

Comment: @Arty, twice slower than a spinlock -- is the expected mutex perf. your spinlock does `store` with `memory_order_release` on exit, you just need to set it free. but mutex would do an interlocked fetch operation, most likely an `exchange`, to see if some waiting threads need to be notified.  (x86 has cheap store with `memory_order_release`, but any `exchange` is not cheap, even `_relaxed`)

Comment: Have you looked at the code? What exactly is your question? Have you compared the features the two support to explain their timing difference? Or is it the size difference, which is not unusual at all if you have a handle/body separation.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**TL;DR:** unfortunate combination of backward compatibility and ABI compatibility issues makes `std::mutex` bad until the next ABI break. OTOH, `std::shared_mutex` is good.

---

A decent implementation of `std::mutex` would try to use an atomic operation to acquire the lock, if busy, possibly would try spinning in a read loop (with some `pause` on x86), and ultimately will resort to OS wait.

There are a couple of ways to implement such `std::mutex`:

1. Directly delegate to corresponding OS APIs that do all of above.
2. Do spinning and atomic thing on its own, call OS APIs only for OS wait.

Sure, the first way is easier to implement, more friendly to debug, more robust. So it appears to be the way to go. The candidate APIs are:

- [`CRITICAL_SECTION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/critical-section-objects) APIs. A recursive mutex, that is lacking static initializer and needs explicit destruction
- [`SRWLOCK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/slim-reader-writer--srw--locks). A non-recursive shared mutex that has static initializer and doesn't need explicit destruction
- [`WaitOnAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitonaddress). An API to wait on particular variable to be changed, similar to Linux [`futex`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html).

These primitives have OS version requirements:

- `CRITICAL_SECTION` existed since I think Windows 95, though [`TryEnterCriticalSection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-tryentercriticalsection) was not present in Windows 9x, but the ability to use `CRITICAL_SECTION` with `CONDITION_VARIABLE` was added since Windows Vista, with `CONDITION_VARIABLE` itself.
- `SRWLOCK` exists since Windows Vista, but [`TryAcquireSRWLockExclusive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-tryacquiresrwlockexclusive) exists since Windows 7, so it can only directly implement `std::mutex` starting in Windows 7.
- `WaitOnAddress` was added since Windows 8.

By the time when `std::mutex` was added, Windows XP support by Visual Studio C++ library was needed, so it was implemented using doing things on its own. In fact, `std::mutex` and other sync stuff was delegated to ConCRT ([Concurrency Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/concrt/concurrency-runtime?view=msvc-170))

For Visual Studio 2015, the implementation was switched to use the best available mechanism, that is `SRWLOCK` starting in Windows 7, and `CRITICAL_SECTION` stating in Windows Vista. ConCRT turned out to be not the best mechanism, but it still was used for Windows XP and 2003. The polymorphism was implemented by making placement new of classes with virtual functions into a buffer provided by `std::mutex` and other primitives.

Note that this implementation breaks the requirement for `std::mutex` to be `constexpr`, because of runtime detection, placement new, and inability of pre-Window 7 implementation to have only static initializer.

As time passed support of Windows XP was finally dropped in VS 2019, and support of Windows Vista was dropped in VS 2022, the change is made to avoid ConCRT usage, the change is planned to avoid even runtime detection of SRWLOCK (disclosure: I've contributed these PRs).

---

Virtual functions were still retained for quite long, because of binary compatibility concerns, until they were removed in Visual Studio 2022. The removal was possible because ABI compatibility of Visual Studio implies that when you mix objects or binaries produced with different toolset versions, the VC Libraries should be from the latest of the mix, or newer.

Removal happened in VS 2022 version 17.10. At the time of this edit, this version is only available as a preview, not production version.

Virtual functions removal allowed to fix long-standing bug that `std::mutex` constructor wasn't `constexpr`. This was because id had to placement new the implementation there. It was not possible to avoid placement new, and make an implementation to construct right inside `std::mutex`, because `std::mutex` has to be standard layout class (see [Why is std::mutex a standard-layout class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69826969/2945027)).

---

So the size overhead comes from the size of ConCRT mutex.

And the runtime overhead comes from the chain of call:

- library function call to get to the standard library implementation
- virtual function call to get to `SRWLOCK`-based implementation (eliminated in VS 2022 17.10)
- finally Windows API call.

Virtual function call is more expensive than usually due to standard library DLLs being built with [`/guard:cf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/guard-enable-control-flow-guard).

A significant part of the runtime overhead is due to `std::mutex` fills in ownership count and locked thread. Even though this information is not required for `SRWLOCK`. It is due to shared internal structure with `recursive_mutex`. The extra information may be helpful for debugging, but it does take time to fill it in.

---

`std::shared_mutex` was designed to support only systems starting Windows 7. So it uses `SRWLOCK` directly.

The size of `std::shared_mutex` is the size of `SRWLOCK`. `SRWLOCK` has the same size as a pointer (though internally it is not a pointer).

It still involves some avoidable overhead: it calls C++ runtime library, just to call Windows API, instead of calling Windows API directly. This looks fixable with the next ABI, though.

`std::shared_mutex` constructor could be constexpr, as `SRWLOCK` does not need dynamic initializer, but the standard prohibits voluntary adding `constexpr` to the standard classes.

Comment: So swapping a std mutex with a shared makes sense, and is relatively future proof, on windows.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, yes. It is likely to become useless in the future, but unlikely to become harmful. However, if you used it with `condition_variable`, it takes `condition_variable_any` to couple with `shared_mutex`, there's no specialized `condition_variable` for `shared_mutex`.

Comment: This is a very enlightening Q&A Alex, thanks! I noticed that you printed out the `sizeof` both mutex types in your question. I'm guessing here, but is the size of the `shared_mutex` 8 because it just contains a pointer to a shared control block?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, I've edited the answer to cover that. There's no shared control block. `SRWLOCK` itself has the same size as a pointer (though internally it is not a pointer). `shared_mutex` just contains `SRWLOCK` by value.

Comment: `TryEnterCriticalSection` is not W2K-only. It is *NT*-only.